# Remove digits but not when part of a word

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove non-alphabet characters from an address, except when they followed by letters.

e.g. I want to remove `7` and `e7` but not `7th`

I think the english translation of the regex exp would be: remove all "words" that don't end with an alphabetic character?

I want to turn

```
850 7th Ave Frnt 1, New York, NY 10019
```

Into

```
7th Ave Frnt, New York, NY
```

Previously I was doing

```
address.replaceAll("\\d","");
```

But when I came up with words like 7th the 7 was disappearing, I want to keep these words entirely.

I've tried this `(\d)$` but this seems to only match the final digit of 10019 (also tried many other variations) all seem far off the mark.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I spent over an hour getting no where!

Comment: over an hour?? Did you forget SO?

Comment: Was trying to read tutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
address.replaceAll("\\b\\d+\\b","");
```

or

Add `\s*`, if you want to remove also the spaces which exists before the number.

```
address.replaceAll("\\s*\\b\\d+\\b\\s*","");
```

Comment: Thanks works, I believe you were first - so will select ... in 12 min.

Comment: or, `(?<!\\S)\\d+(?!\\S)`

Answer (score 4):

```
\\b\\d+\\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/7

`\b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`

or using `lookaheads`.

```
(?:^|(?<=\W))\d+(?=\W|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/8